# Where can I browse the package database using a web-browser

Tags: package-management, www

I'm looking for the Ubuntu equivalent of http://debian.org/distrib/packages.

Answer (score 0):

The direct equivalent of the site is:

http://packages.ubuntu.com

> This site provides you with information about all the packages available in the Ubuntu Package archive.

[image]